# how to insert csv data to an oracle table?

Tags: oracle, shell, sh, ksh

Hi I am new to shell scripting and trying to insert data in a csv file which i generated to an oracle database table. my code is below

```
FilePath =/oracle/some path
Filename=test.csv

X='sqlplus -s username/password@dbname<< EOF
          set heading off pages 0 feedback off
       SELECT  a.user_id,a.email_id FROM addresses a where 
       a.user_id in('ABCD','EFGH','IJKL','MNOP');
              EXIT           
         EOF`

         While read line
         do
         echo $line
    sqlplus -s username/password@dbname<< EOF
insert into sometable (uid,email) values ($line);
commit; 
exit
EOF
done<<
```

Can someone tell me what i amdoing wrong as data is not getting inserted.A sample working code will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Looks like something when wrong when you posted your code, the syntax is completely off. Please [edit] your question to insert your real code.

Comment: Are you trying to read from a CSV file and insert into a table?  Because that's what your question says. But your shell script is rather confusing.

Comment: There are tools to load delimited data, such as SQL\*Loader.

Comment: yes.I am trying to read from  a csv file and then upload the same to DB.

Comment: I tried the sqlldr tool and it has worked fine.

Comment: However it is peculiar that if i try to insert just one column it works fine.but when i try to insert two columns it generates bad file.i will share complete code so that you can review.